# Nuxt 2.16 SSR meta data on GCP not working

Tags: nuxt.js

I currently have:

```
async asyncData({ store, route }) {
  const postMeta = await store.dispatch('modules/post/get', route.params.id)
  return {
    postMeta
  }
},
head() {
  // const something = this.$store.getters['modules/post'] // <------- this.$store
  return {
    title: this.postMeta.title,
    meta: [
      { hid: 'og:image', name: 'og:image', content: this.postMeta.mainImage },
      { hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: this.postMeta.description },
      { hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: this.postMeta.swapProps }
    ]
  }
},
```

it doesn't work. I've tried pretty much all ways imaginable with the docs on the interwebs. fetch no. explicitly setting "SocialHead" component in parent, etc. Many etc's here.

Error on client is currently saying "title" undefined.

when i do:

```
 meta: [
          { hid: 'og:image', name: 'og:image', content: this.post.mainImage },
          { hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: this.post.description },
          { hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: this.post.swapProps }
        ]
```

in vue dev tools it does this:

$metaInfo:Object
meta:Array[3]
0:Object
content:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/correct-url.com/o/posts%2F7Q8MGUXRF1RHAQXUKDVWIT?alt=media&token=740240ff-e8ad-4aa9-8bf0-52c42b529521"
hid:"og:image"
name:"og:image"
1:Object
content:"great vessel. 34 feet. well cared and loved."
hid:"og:description"
name:"og:description"
2:Object
title:"Sailboat"

which makes me think im doing something right, but when live on server it doesn't reflect this, only shows what I have on nuxt.config and my page head doens't reflect..

The dispatch action sets my post on client and server (asyncData). Should these be different commits??

At a loss.

Thanks for insight.

edit:

tried this as well;

```
   head() {
      return {
        title: "Page title",
        meta: [
          { hid: 'og:title', name: 'og:title', content: this.title.stringValue },
          { hid: 'og:image', name: 'og:image', content: this.mainImage.stringValue },
        ]
      }
    },
    async asyncData ({ route }) {
      return axios.get(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/correct-url/databases/(default)/documents/posts/` + route.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        return {
          ...response.data.fields
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

NOTHING.

this way:

```
head() {
      console.log("asdasdasdasdasdasd", this.title)
      return {
        title: "asdasd",
        meta: [
          { hid: 'og:title', name: 'og:title', content: this.title },
          { hid: 'og:image', name: 'og:image', content: this.image },
        ]
      }
    },
    async asyncData ({ route }) {
      return axios.get(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/correct-url/databases/(default)/documents/posts/` + route.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        return {
          title: response.data.fields.title.stringValue,
          image: response.data.fields.mainImage.stringValue
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

NOTHING!

and for some reason on page source it goes to the bottom and here:

window.__NUXT__=(function(a,b){return {layout:"default",data:[{title:"Sailboat",image:"https:\correct-url\u002Fo\u002Fposts%2F7Q8MGUXRF1RHAQXUKDVWIT?alt=media&token=740240ff-e8ad-4aa9-8bf0-52c42b529521"